# Function Print PHP echo

Tags: php

Someone knows what's my wrong code :

```
$text = str_replace(":-)", "<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>", $text);
```

When I try to print the text using PHP echo, it show :

```
<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>
```

All I want to do is to show the image when I input :-)

Thank you.

As per details, this is my code below :

```
function sendChat() {
$from = $_SESSION['username'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$_SESSION['openChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

$messagesan = sanitize($message);

if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']])) {
    $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] = '';
}

$_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] .= <<<EOD
                   {
        "s": "1",
        "f": "{$to}",
        "m": "{$messagesan}"
   },
EOD;


unset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']]);

$sql = "insert into chat (chat.from,chat.to,message,send) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($from)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($message)."',NOW())";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo "1";
exit(0);
}

function sanitize($text) {
$text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
$text = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$text);
$text = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$text);
$text = str_replace("\n","<br>",$text);
$text = str_replace(":-)", "<img src='emoticons/13.gif'>", $text);
return $text;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is... that looks like your code is working!

Comment: You do mderstand you have your parameters backwards

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No, the parameters are in the right order: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Can you post you echo code? It sounds like you are html encoding the output so it is writing it out as text rather then html.

Comment: var_dump($text); before and after str_replace

Comment: Can you clarify what is your problem and post whatever your echo code?

Comment: hi.. please see the detail on my top post.. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

---

> **Edit:** do you even have PHP installed locally? PHP scripts need things like EasyPHP installed locally.

---

Sounds like a bad Content-Type header.

Normally this gets set automatically but you can try enforcing it and make sure you have everything.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html'); ?>
<html><head></head><body>
    <?php 
         $text = 'OK BOSS :-) ';
         $text = str_replace(':-)', '<img src="emoticons/smile.gif" />', $text);
         echo $text;
    ?>
</body></html>
```